# How to have collapsible slideshow collapsed by default rather than sliding up?

Tags: javascript

I would like the slideshow to be collapsed by default. Right now when going to this page http://dev-caal.gotpantheon.com/membership we can see the slideshows for a split second and it then slides up. I would like it to be collapsed by default.

[image]

This is the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.jcarousel-clip').slideUp();
$(".jcarousel-prev, .jcarousel-next").hide();
$('.updown3').click(function() {
  $('.jcarousel-clip ').slideToggle(300, function() {
    $('.updown3').toggleClass('arrow-up');
    $(".jcarousel-prev, .jcarousel-next").toggle(); 
    return false;
  });
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

Render it off the page, collapse it, then inject it into the area you would like

or you can try doing  `element.hide().slideUp(function(){this.show();});`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `display: none` to `.jcarousel` in your css file and only show it afterwards.